# Unable to use turtle in Git Bash

Tags: python, git-bash

I have only just begun to learn to code in Python. I have a bit of experience in HTML, but that's about it.

I am current taking the Intro to Programming nanodegree from Udacity.

The lessons I am working on is introducing students to using interactive mode via command line to test bits of code. The problem is that I have to use the python -i command to get into interactive mode, and I am unable to scroll through the history. The bigger problem, however, is that running things like the turtle module are spotty.

Following the instructions in the lesson, I am trying to run the following code:

```
import turtle

amy = turtle.Turtle()
amy.forward(100)
amy.left(90)
amy.forward(100)
```

etc...

What ends up happening is I am able to import the turtle, assign it the name "amy", but then when I try to give it movement commands, nothing happens. the >>> disappears and Git Bash stops responding. I have to close the terminal and start a new terminal everything.

Also, being unable to use the arrow keys to cycle through command history is frustrating and retyping the code over and over again any time a mistake is time consuming.

Are there any better ways to go about using the CLI to fulfill the requirements of the course? (I didn't say which requirements, because I'm not entirely sure to what extent the course will require me to utilize the CLI on upcoming projects.)

This problem has frustrated me so much and I am not able to get any useful information from the "mentors" on the Udacity forums, so I have basically stopped progressing through the course.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative would be to use, instead of a git bash shell, a true Linux session [through WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#whats-new-in-wsl-2) if you are using a recent enough Windows version.

That way, you would benefit from a regular shell, in which history would be available through arrow keys to cycle through.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same course and had the same problem.  Found a solution at [https://granatguitar.com/why-can't-i-run-python-in-git-bash-on-windows/](https://granatguitar.com/why-can%27t-i-run-python-in-git-bash-on-windows/)

I tested it first from the $ prompt and it seemed to work OK, so then I set it up in .bash_profile.

I didn't have a .bash_profile file so I created one in ~ and edited it as granat suggested.
I added the line    alias pythoni="winpty python"   and saved the file.  (I used pythoni rather than python because, well, it's python interactive.)

Now, when I enter pythoni at the $ prompt it starts python in interactive mode....and it works!  All the problems with hanging and not moving the turtles have gone.

Comment: Please don't post links to answers. That link is broken so now your answer is useless.